# Undefined object method ONLY in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, object, mongomapper

I have a Day object which contains some statistics and is updated daily. Here's the two errors I'm getting:

> undefined method `top_light_snown' for #
>
> undefined method `top_agents_snown' for #

Depending on the contents of the view:

```
<h3 class='thin underline'>Daily Breakdown:</h3>
<%# debug @today %>
<%# @today.methods %>
Top User Agents Today: <%= @today.top_agents_snown %>
<br>
Top Keyword Triggers <%= @today.top_keyword_triggers %>
<br>
Top URLs Visited <%= @today.top_urls_visited %>
<br>
Top Injections Shown <%= @today.top_inj_shown %>
<br>
Top Popups Shown <%= @today.top_pop_shown %>
<br>
Top Custom Injections Shown <%= @today.top_cust_shown %>
<br>
Top Lightboxes Shown <%# @today.top_light_snown %>
<br>
Top Global Injections Shown <%= @today.top_glob_shown %>
```

Note that only .top_light_shown and .top_agents_shown cause errors. All the other methods work perfectly fine. Also note the two commented out debug commands. The result of debug @today shows that it does indeed have an attribute "top_light_shown," it is also present in the list of methods from @today.methods, along with all the other ones used.

Here's the contents of the controller - as you can see, I'm setting up the new @today Day object and pre-filling it with junk data to see if I could access it from the view. In this case, the if statement will always fail (but even if it doesn't, I have the same undefined method errors)

```
if Day.find_by_id(Time.now.day)
      stats_today = Day.find_by_id(Time.now.day)
      @ads_today = stats_today.top_inj_shown.size + stats_today.top_pop_shown.size + stats_today.top_cust_shown.size + stats_today.top_light_shown.size + stats_today.top_glob_shown.size
      @total_pageviews = Day.find_by_id(Time.now.day).pageviews
      @today = Day.find_by_id(Time.now.day)
    else
      @today = Day.new(:top_agents_shown => ['Firefox', 'Chrome'], :top_light_shown => ['l-TEST', 'l-TEST2'])
      puts @today.top_light_shown
      puts @today.top_agents_shown
      @ads_today = 'ERROR'
      @total_pageviews = 'ERROR'
    end
```

Here's the server log after requesting the page with the puts working perfectly fine in the controller:

> Started GET "/assets/favicons/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-01
>   19:13:03 -0600 Served asset /favicons/favicon.ico - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
>
> l-TEST l-TEST2 Firefox Chrome
>
> Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-01 19:16:38 -0600
>   Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML

Finally, here's the contents of the Day.rb:

```
class Day
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :number,            Integer

    key :pageviews,         Integer
    key :shown_injs,        Integer
    key :shown_pops,        Integer
    key :shown_custs,       Integer
    key :shown_lights,      Integer
    key :shown_globs,       Integer

    key :top_agents_shown,      Array
    key :top_keyword_triggers,  Array
    key :top_urls_visited,      Array
    key :top_inj_shown,     Array
    key :top_pop_shown,     Array
    key :top_cust_shown,        Array
    key :top_light_shown,       Array
    key :top_glob_shown,        Array

end
```

What in the world is going on? Why are the IDENTICAL methods with a different name work and others do not? Why those particular two? Why do they work in the controller and not in the view?

Comment: Your view calls @today.top_agents_snown, but you define top_agents_shown.  Is this misspelling in your code, too?

Comment: I'm sorry? .top_agents_shown is defined in the model as a method for Day, then @today becomes an instance of Day.new - therefore it should have that method, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view calls @today.top_agents_snown, but you define top_agents_shown.  Just a misspelling.  Some days are like that!